# Stopping checking a conditional while looping over an iterable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

so I have the following question. Let's say that we're doing a standard "password strength check", meaning that if a password (a string) has an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, and a number in it, it's considered to be "strong"
super simple example of what I have in mind:

```
for character in 'asdASD123':
  if character.isupper():
    something
  if character.islower():
    something
  if character.isnumeric():
    something
```

and if all of these conditions at any point are met, then the password is strong. And my question: Is it somehow possible to stop checking a certain condition if it already has been met? In this example, the "islower" condition will be satisfied on the very first character. Is there a way to eliminate it from being checked in further loops? If so, how to do that? Is there a way to store the conditions in a list, and then remove them from that list once they are met, or something to that effect?

Comment: What you can do is do the opposite like check if no lowercase letter is present or no special characters are present and at the last, simply the password is set. Also there is no need for a for loop

Comment: @Cbhihe what happens if e.g. the first character is the only numeric one?

Comment: @Cbhihe i see. so you are proposing a solution with multiple `for` loops? still not sure what you mean by 'indent each successive conditional' then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, by introducing flags (boolean indicators) to keep track of which checks have already passed:

```
upper_flag = False
lower_flag = False
numeric_flag = False

for character in 'asdASD123':
  if character.isupper() and not upper_flag:
    something
    upper_flag = True
  if character.islower() and not lower_flag:
    something
    lower_flag = True
  if character.isnumeric() and not numeric_flag:
    something
    numeric_flag = True
```

That being said, if the goal is to save time, the password would have to be very long in order to save significant amounts of time (or you would have to check very many passwords).

On the other hand, the flags can have other uses, like storing or displaying how many of the checks a given password passes. A quick and dirty example is given below, but more likely than printing it, you'd like to store this information somehow.

```
def password_checker(password):
    upper_flag = False
    lower_flag = False
    numeric_flag = False
    
    for character in password:
        if character.isupper() and not upper_flag:
            upper_flag = True
        if character.islower() and not lower_flag:
            lower_flag = True
        if character.isnumeric() and not numeric_flag:
            numeric_flag = True
            
    flag_list = [upper_flag, lower_flag, numeric_flag]
    
    print(f"Password: '{password}' passes {sum(flag_list)}/{len(flag_list)} checks:\n")
    print("  - Contains upper case character:\t", upper_flag )
    print("  - Contains lower case character:\t", lower_flag )
    print("  - Contains numeric  character:  \t", numeric_flag )

password_checker('asdASD123')
```

Returns:

```
Password: 'asdASD123' passes 3/3 checks:

  - Contains upper case character:   True
  - Contains lower case character:   True
  - Contains numeric  character:     True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
passwd = "sdnkdj98KJ/"

def passcheck(passwd):
    upper = any(map(lambda x:x.isupper(),passwd))
    num = any(map(lambda x:x.isnumeric(),passwd))
    lower = any(map(lambda x:x.islower(),passwd))
    return "strong passwd" if upper and lower and num else "weak passwd"
```

Per comment, I add a benchmark on the difference in performance between two provided solutions, for 100,000 replications. To be fair to the other solution's author, I encapsulated my solution in a function declaration block as well, since those consume CPU time as well.

My answer:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()
for i in range(100000):        
    a = passcheck(passwd)

print(datetime.now()-start)   # output: 0:00:00.205365, so 205.4ms
```

davinci1913's answer:

```
start = datetime.now()
for i in range(100000):
    password_checker(passwd)

print(datetime.now()-start)  # output: 0:00:00.225257, so 225ms
```

So my answer happens to be a tiny bit faster, but I would not pay much attention to that difference of 20ms. Mostly my answer is more concise and in that case more readable. Both methods will perform well.

Comment: that is practically character for character what I managed to come up with before I checked the answers to this solution ;) checkmarked the other solution, because it introduced a new approach. Wonder which one performs better though

Comment: @entman: added benchmarking so you can see which answer is faster.

Answer (score 1):

for such a case i would recommend regex to avoid loops

```
import re

password= 'asdASD1'

pattern = re.compile(r"^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])")
if re.match(pattern, password): #if it meets condition
    # do somethin
```

Comment: +1 : Nice and concise Ade_1, but look at my solution. I only use base methods and no regex while also avoiding `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `|` (logical 'or') is short-circuiting to eliminate the check once the condition is met.

By short-circuiting, I mean that if there is some expression: `x | y`, then `y` is only evaluated if `x` is `False`.

This allows for some concision also. E.g.

```
contains_upper   = False
contains_lower   = False
contains_numeric = False

for char in "asdASD123":
    contains_upper   |= char.isupper()
    contains_lower   |= char.islower()
    contains_numeric |= char.isnumeric()

strong = contains_upper and contains_lower and contains_numeric
```

I feel that this code is quite idiomatic Python and quite readable.

Comment: This *is* pythonic, but doesn't solve the question, because each function is being executed for each character. The goal is to only execute subsequent functions if the previous one succeeds.

Comment: @blueteeth my point is that since the `|` is short-circuiting, the functions are actually not executed once the corresponding condition is `True`. Is that not the case?

Comment: Ah yes. Nice, I hadn't realised that.

Comment: I did not know the idiom `|=`. You taught me something: plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for that. You could do the following

```
super_cond = False
lower_cond = False
numeric_cond = False
for character in 'asdASD123':
    if not super_cond and character.isupper():
        super_cond = True
        #something
    if not lower_cond and character.islower():
        lower_cond = True
        #something
    if not numeric_cond and character.isnumeric():
        numeric_cond = True
        #something
```

If you want to use lists you can do

```
conditions = [False,False,False]
for character in 'asdASD123':
    if not conditions[0] and character.isupper():
        conditions[0] = True
        #something
    if not conditions[1] and character.islower():
        conditions[1] = True
        #something
    if not conditions[2] and character.isnumeric():
        conditions[2] = True
        #something
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there are many ways you can do this.

#### Here is one example

You can create a dictionary with `True`/`False` values.
**Like this:**

```
is_obj = {'upper': False, 'lower': False, 'numeric': False}
for character in 'asdASD123':
  if character.isupper() and is_obj['upper'] == False:
    is_obj['upper'] = True
  if character.islower() and is_obj['lower'] == False:
    is_obj['lower'] = True
  if character.isnumeric() and is_obj['numeric'] == False:
    is_obj['numeric'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways you can try that, one of method can be like this:

```
is_lower, is_upper, is_numeric = False, False, False
for character in 'asdASD123':
    if is_lower and is_upper and is_numeric:
        return "Strong password"   #print("Strong Password")
    if character.isupper() and not is_upper:
        is_upper = True
        something
    if character.islower() and not is_lower:
        is_lower = True
        something
    if character.isnumeric() and not is_numeric:
        is_numeric = True
        something
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably the best for this, but here's a solution where the loop is in a different place. This can be modified not to do the same loop every time.

I've wrapped every function so you can see what actually gets called.

```
def print_and(fun_name):
    def wrapper(c):
        fun = getattr(c, fun_name)
        result = fun()
        print(f"'{c}'.{fun_name} == {result}")
        return result
    return wrapper

is_lower = print_and("islower")
is_upper = print_and("isupper")
is_digit = print_and("isdigit")

def check_characters(characters):
    return (
        any(is_lower(c) for c in characters)
        and any(is_upper(c) for c in characters)
        and any(is_digit(c) for c in characters)
    )

print(bool(check_characters("asdASD123")))
print(bool(check_characters("123")))
```

gets this result:

```
'a'.islower == True
'a'.isupper == False
's'.isupper == False
'd'.isupper == False
'A'.isupper == True
'a'.isdigit == False
's'.isdigit == False
'd'.isdigit == False
'A'.isdigit == False
'S'.isdigit == False
'D'.isdigit == False
'1'.isdigit == True
True
'1'.islower == False
'2'.islower == False
'3'.islower == False
False
```

You can see that each function only gets called when the previous one has returned true. The improvement to this would be to only check the rest of the string from the point the previous function exits.